# Assembly language - what does sarq do in the code?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering

I am trying to translate assembly code back into C code but I noticed this one operation called sarq. I think q is for what size the address is but I do not know what the sarq does to the address. I commented on what I believe the code does.

```
.LC0    .string "ans %d\n" 
main:
.LFB0:                  val = -8(%rbp), result = -12(%rbp)
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movabsq $53162464113523643, %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)      //val(variable) address -8,inputs value in %rax
        movl    $0, -12(%rbp)       //result(variable) address -12, inputs 0
        jmp     .L2         //starts loop
.L3:
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax      //moves value in val into rax
        andl    $1, %eax        //dunno what eax is but adds 1 into it
        xorl    %eax, -12(%rbp)     //compares the value of eax and result to see if they are not equal. so compares 1 to 0
        sarq    -8(%rbp)        //does something to val?
.L2:
        cmpq    $0, -8(%rbp)        //compares val to 0
        jg      .L3         //if greater, goes to L3
        movl    -12(%rbp), %eax     //else, moves value from result into eax
        movl    %eax, %esi      //moves eax into esi
        movl    $.LC0, %edi     //Moves w/e $.LC0 is into edi. Based on the top, edi now holds that string?
        movl    $0, %eax        //moves 0 into eax
        call    printf          //print statement
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: [SAR is documented in Intel's insn set ref manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sar` is an arithmetic right shift. The single operand form shifts its operand right by one place, filling the topmost bit with the sign of the number. the suffix `q` indicates that the operand is a 64 bit operand (a quadword). Thus `sarq -8(%rbp)` shifts the quadword eight bytes below `%rbp` right by one place.

Comment: So I would convert that top number into binary, shift it over 1 and add a 0 infront of it? So the operation would be if result != 1, then shift it over?

Comment: @JMei: b63 (the most significant bit) keeps it's value (sign). For bits b62 to b0 the shift right by one place means, that b_i = b_old_i+1. So 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA will turn into 0xD555555555555555. `shr` would fill b63 with zero. `sal` and `shl` will both shift value left (same result). `sarq` is almost signed division of integer, except `sar(-1) == -1` again. Why don't you simply check the x86 instruction set reference guide, and then search for some tutorial for bit-shifting instructions? If you want to RE anything, you should have the instruction set ref. by hand anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

`andl    $1, %eax        //dunno what eax is but adds 1 into it`

Uhmm... `eax` is lower 32b part of `rax`. And it's not `add`, but `and`. So from the quad value only the least significant bit (`b0`) will remain in `eax`.

That one is xor-ed with result value (initially zero).

And the quad value is shifted to right, by signed shift, but the constant is positive (`0x00BCDEFABCDEFBBB`), so doesn't matter. Otherwise that code would end in infinite loop, for negative constant! Human programmer would use `shr` in this case, so the function would work for any 64b value.

So the whole code calculates parity of that long constant (in quite ineffective way, plus it looks like unoptimized code), and then prints it as "ans #\n", where # is 0 (even count of set bits) or 1 (odd).

(I didn't debug it, just going after quick look on it, so maybe I missed something, you should try in debugger, what it really does).

---

BTW, good job with those comments, at least it was easy to point to you another problem. Without them nobody would notice, and only `sarq` would be answered.